# php/mysqli mysqli_insert_id() getting current id and re-inserting to another table

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I'm not really sure how to use this mysqli_insert_id() function but here's what I'm trying to do!

forum_threads.sql has auto incr.

```
if(isset($_POST['createThread'])) {
    $db->real_query("INSERT INTO forum_threads (cata_id) VALUES ('1')");
    $id = mysqli_insert_id();
    $db->real_query("INSERT INTO forum_replies (thread_id) VALUES ('" .$id. ")");
}
```

I need the thread_id (when inserting into forum_replies) to be the current id (which is a row inside forum_threads and also is auto incr.)

Comment: What is the error your having

Comment: Did you try a manual page by chance?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['createThread'])) {
    $db->real_query("INSERT INTO forum_threads (cata_id) VALUES ('1')");
    $id = $db->insert_id;
    $db->real_query("INSERT INTO forum_replies (thread_id) VALUES ('" .$id. ")");
}
```